# MongoDB - strange behaviour of query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this two documents in my mongoDB database:

```
db.DocumentFile.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("587f39910cc0fec092bdb10c"),
"_class" : "com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement.dao.domain.DocumentFile",
"fileName" : "DocumentFile1",
"ending" : "jpg",
"projectId" : "587f39910cc0fec092bdb10b",
"active" : true,
"userIdBlackList" : [
    "587f39910cc0fec092bdb10a"
]
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("587f39910cc0fec092bdb10d"),
"_class" : "com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement.dao.domain.DocumentFile",
"fileName" : "DocumentFile2",
"ending" : "jpg",
"projectId" : "587f39910cc0fec092bdb10b",
"active" : true,
"userIdBlackList" : [ ]
}
```

I have this code in order to get amount of query:

```
final Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("‌​userIdBlackList").nin(userId));

final Long amount = mongoTemplate.count(query, DocumentFile.class);
return amount.intValue();
```

The amount is 2 in this case what is wrong - it should be 1.
The query in Query object looks like this:

```
Query: { "‌​userIdBlackList" : { "$nin" : [ "587f39910cc0fec092bdb10a"]}}
```

If I copy this query and made a query for the mongodb console like this:

```
db.DocumentFile.find({ "‌​userIdBlackList" : { "$nin" : [ "587f39910cc0fec092bdb10a"]}}).pretty()
```

I get an amount of two, what if wrong because one document includes **587f39910cc0fec092bdb10a** in userIdBlackList -> it should be one.

With this query command:

```
db.DocumentFile.find({userIdBlackList: { "$nin": ["587f39910cc0fec092bdb10a"] } }).pretty();
```

I get the right result, I am really confused at the moment.
Does anyone have any idea?
Maybe the problem ist that one time **userIdBlackList** is with quotation mark ("userIdBlackList") and the other time it isn't.

Comment: Are you storing mongoIds in userIdBlackList array field? Or string?

Comment: Strings, the id Strings uf the users

Comment: It is really crazy, I used user strings, its not working, than @DBRef to User Object, not working, now ObjectId's, still not working. Actually itis not clear for my why this makes such probelms with Spring Data and MongoDB

Comment: Are you connecting to the same MongoDB? Check if in MongoDb factory you set different database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the unintentional formatting picked up for `"userIdBlackList"`. Your string is interpreted with non printing characters in the `"??userIdBlackList"` for all your search queries. I see little transparent square boxes when I copy your queries to mongo shell.

That tells me their is some encoding issue. Clear that formatting and see if that helps you.

Both `$ne` and `$nin` should work!